# SOQL How to select WHERE = 2 months ago

Tags: soql, date

I'm tying to retrieve data from the 2 months ago. I tried `WHERE = LAST_N_MONTHS:2` but this returns data from last month too. So for now I want everything from 1st July - 31st July. This needs to update each month too.

On the same subject how do I get the same but for last month last year e.g. 1st Aug 16 - 31st Aug 16?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work for records from two months ago (i.e. - Today is 25th September, that means 1st July - 31st July):

```
WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:2 AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_MONTHS:1
```

And the second query for records from 13 months ago, which is the previous month of last year (i.e. - Today is 25th Sep. 2016, so this will return 1st August - 31st August 2015):

```
WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:13 AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_MONTHS:12
```

Answer (score 0):

The last `Last_N_Months` would also give the last day of the previous month. Suppose I want to process previous Nov/21 data from today then the below query would also give me data of 31st October/21 which you don't want to process. So the best workaround to be more accurate is to use the exact date as given below:

```
CreatedDate >= 2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z AND CreatedDate <= 2021-11-30T00:00:00.000Z Order By CreatedDate ASC
```

Now this will give you the exact record of that specific month. Like in this case it's giving me all the records only of Nov31.